# Is there a method for displaying plots after plt.show() with sphinx or keep scope after .. plot::

Tags: python-sphinx, numpydoc

I am using sphinx with `numpydocs`, `doctest`, and the scipy theme.

When using `.. plot::` in a docstring, the plots are all created, except instead of showing where they are called, they all move to the end of the documentation. Is there a way to force it inline, without needed to rewrite the example in an `.rst` file?  This is what my `example.py` file docstring looks like:

```
.. plot::

    >>> import numpy as np
    >>> import matplotlib.pylab as plt

    # commentary breaking the block 
    Finished Imports

    >>> x = np.linspace(-np.pi*2, np.pi*2, 2000)
    >>> y = np.sin(x)
    >>> plt.plot(x, y)#doctest: +SKIP
    >>> plt.show()#doctest: +SKIP

First plot should be here

    >>> x2 = x
    >>> plt.plot(x2, y)#doctest: +SKIP
    >>> plt.show()#doctest: +SKIP

Second plot should be here
```

....

`But both are here.`

Alternatively, I tried adding another `.. plot::` method but it changes scope.

```
.. plot::

    >>> import numpy as np
    >>> import matplotlib.pylab as plt

    # commentary breaking the block 
    Finished Imports

    >>> x = np.linspace(-np.pi*2, np.pi*2, 2000)
    >>> y = np.sin(x)
    >>> plt.plot(x, y)#doctest: +SKIP
    >>> plt.show()#doctest: +SKIP

First plot should be here

.. plot::

    >>> x2 = x
    >>> plt.plot(x2, y)#doctest: +SKIP
    >>> plt.show()#doctest: +SKIP
```

Which when using `make html` will state `x` is not defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were two issues I ran into that are now resolved.  For one, I wasn't getting all the updates correctly displayed, so I need to run `make clean` before `make html` each time.

The solution to the original problem though is to add `:context: close-figs` after `.. plot::` each time `plot.show()` is called.

```
.. plot::
    :context: close-figs
```

So my docstring now looks like:

```
.. plot::
    :context: close-figs

    >>> import numpy as np
    >>> import matplotlib.pylab as plt

    # commentary breaking the block 
    Finished Imports

    >>> x = np.linspace(-np.pi*2, np.pi*2, 2000)
    >>> y = np.sin(x)
    >>> plt.plot(x, y)#doctest: +SKIP
    >>> plt.show()#doctest: +SKIP

.. plot::
    :context: close-figs

First plot shows here

    >>> x2 = x
    >>> plt.plot(x2, y)#doctest: +SKIP
    >>> plt.show()#doctest: +SKIP

.. plot::
    :context: close-figs

Second plot shows here
```